# Image Displaying Only When Text is Active

Tags: html, css, forms, image

I'm making a copy of the MSN.com Webpage for practice with my HTML and CSS. I've managed to get the header, and everything above it except the search form. Now I know how to make forms, I just don't understand how one of the little pieces works

For Example:

Look at the follow picture:
http://gyazo.com/497d24dde39c04d9956c2faec4eb556f

You can see where it says MSN (orange part), the arrow/triangle is located right underneath it. I assume this arrow is an image, correct? You can't just make it through CSS?

So I want to know how I would go about having an arrow that is default at the first word, and then relocates to the active link/text.

Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A simple grey arrow like MSN is using can actually be made using CSS. To make it follow the selected link, you will need to use JavaScript. Don't worry, it's very simple.

First, here's a live example on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/EBhVu/23/

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="active">Web</a> 
<a href="#">MSN</a>
<a href="#">Images</a>
```

**CSS:**

This will build the small grey arrow and place it under the selected link

```
a  {
    position:relative;
}
a:active:after, a.active:after  {
    position:absolute;
    right:50%; /* Centers arrow */
    top:100%; /* Places arrow below link */
    content:" ";
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent; /* Builds the arrow */
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid grey;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

Every time a link is clicked this JavaScript will give the clicked link the class of "active"

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
    $('a').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Also, how do I make it so the first "a" begins as active when the webpage starts. This way the arrow is already started on the "Web" when the webpage opens.

Comment: You're welcome! Just add the class of "active" to whichever link you want to have active when the webpage starts. I updated my answer and the example on jsfiddle.